# import scalaz.syntax.traverse._ outside the object does not work

Tags: scala, scalaz

On scala7.0.6: the following program works:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object Playground extends App {
  val smallNumbers = List(1,2,3,4,5)
  val doubleSmall: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x < 30) Some(x * 2) else None

  import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

  println(smallNumbers.traverse(doubleSmall))
}
```

However, if I move the `import scalaz.syntax.traverse._` outside the object `Playground`, on top of the file, then I get:

```
Error: value traverse is not a member of List[Int]
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import `Scalaz._` and `scalaz.syntax.traverse._` within the same scope:

```
<ToTraverseOps: error> is not a valid implicit value for
  Wrapper.Playground.smallNumbers.type => ?{def traverse: ?} because:
reference to ToTraverseOps is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
and import Scalaz._
           println(smallNumbers.traverse(doubleSmall))
```

If `Scalaz._` and `scalaz.syntax.traverse._` are imported in different (nested) scopes there is no conflict, the latter shadows the former. Or you can completely drop `import scalaz.syntax.traverse._`, it will compile.

`scalac` has flag `-Xlog-implicits` which helps.